# loading and updating a view with two partialview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using C#, MVC, Razor

I'm having a hard time grasping how to perform a model load on two partial views and also updating those views with new information as the user enters it.

I have a regular view that contains this:

```
    @model Myapp.ViewModels.SearchedUser
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">User</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Groups</a></li>
</ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @Html.Partial("_Edit"); 
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{Html.Partial("_Groups");}
    </div>
</div>
```

Originally, the user displayed on the main view.  However, I need to update/add/delete groups from a user and started to move this towards a tabbed page when adding in that code.

So on the partial view for edit, I have:

```
    @model Myapp.ViewModels.SearchedUser
    ...display code for user
```

I'm feeling the @model here may be redundant from the main view.

My group partial view looks like this:

```
@model Myapp.ViewModels.AllGroups

<!--at if (Model.AddGroups != null)
{ -->
    <h2>Groups to be Added</h2>

    <table id="AddGroupList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Until
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Group in Model.CurrentGroups)
            { 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.GroupName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.EndDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model=> Group.bRemove)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (AuthCheck.CheckUser(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), oRoles.StaffChangeRequest) || 
                        AuthCheck.CheckUser(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), oRoles.StudentChangeRequest))
                        { 
                            <span>@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveGroup", new { id = Group.ID })</span>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I do need to pass an IDnum  to each partial view to load the current model for that user.

Now question is...

Am I better off adding in the groups into the SearchedUser model and reloading the whole model each time the adds a group into the user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question.
If your asking how to render a view that contains two partial view calls with different models then you should have a main view with a view model that contains 2 other view models.

```
class MainViewModel
{
PartialOneViewModel {get;set;}
PartialTwoViewModel {get;set;}
}

class PartialOneViewModel
{
// props
}

class PartialTwoViewModel
{
// props
}
```

The main view model should have:
@model MainViewModel

The partials should have their own view model.
Your post should recieve "MainViewModel" with both partials.

Comment: Ok, that answers that... but with that said, when adding a new item to my partial view am I passing the mainviewmodel back everytime and then updating the overall view with that mainviewmodel?

Comment: It's up to you.
You can either post back the "main model" on each change or create two nested forms and post the specific form.

You can also handle this in an ajax way and add exactly what you want in your post.